# HQL(hibernate) timestamp range match

Tags: java, hibernate, timestamp, hql

I need to write a query to get an object between a range of time, currently the query looks like this:

```
Timestamp from = ... 
Timestamp to = ...

getHibernateTemplate().find("from " + Person.class.getName() + " ml where ml.lastModifiedOn>="+from.toString()+" and m1.lastModifiedOn<=" + to.toString());
```

However, this doesnot work for obvious reasons. How can I format the timestamp to be acceptable by the query.

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: unexpected token: 16 near line 1, column 123 [from Person ml where ml.lastModifiedOn>=2010-02-12 16:00:21.292 and m1.lastModifiedOn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing single quotes in your current query. The following should work:

```
from Person ml where ml.lastModifiedOn 
between '2010-02-12 16:00:21.292' and '2010-02-12 23:00:21.292'
```

Note that I don't know why you're not passing `Date` instances to the following query:

```
from Person ml where ml.lastModifiedOn between :from and :to
```

Are you using `java.sql.Timestamp` here? If yes, you shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, I am using Timestamp basically throughout the project, and though this works:
Timestamp from =..;
Timestamp to = ..;
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Person.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("lastModifiedOn", from, to));
List<Person> results = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass a `long` (`from.getTime()`) in the comparison, if it is represented as long in the DB.

Otherwise you can use these functiomns: `second(...), minute(...), hour(...), day(...), month(...), and year(...)`

Comment: In the DB it is represented as DATETIME and not as long. 

How would I use those functions for a whole datetime match ?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
    String sql = "from " + Person.class.getName() + " ml where ml.lastModifiedOn>= ? and m1.lastModifiedOn<= ?";
    Date from = ...;
    Date to = ...;

    getHibernateTemplate().find(sql, new Object[] {from,to});
```

Comment: I tried that and I get an error.

[ERROR] 13:58:03 PARSER -  Invalid path: 'm1.lastModifiedOn'
[ERROR] 13:58:03 PARSER - <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
[ERROR] 13:58:03 PARSER -  left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: Invalid path: 'm1.lastModifiedOn' [from it.Person ml where ml.lastModifiedOn>=? and m1.lastModifiedOn<=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'm1.lastModifiedOn' [from it.Person ml where ml.lastModifiedOn>=? and m1.lastModifiedOn<=?]
...

strange!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query for something between you can do the following:

```
 public List findPerson() {
   Date from = ...;
   Date to = ...;
   return entityManager.createQuery(
     "SELECT p from Person p WHERE p.lastModifiedOn BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2")
     .setParameter(1,from, TemporalType.DATE)
     .setParameter(2,to, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
}
```

You might need to change `TemporalType.DATE` to whatever you are using