# Hibernate Date Criteria fails but HQL works

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, date, restrictions

Hibernate seems to incorrectly handle date ranges using the Criterion API in Oracle. The SQL Query itself seems correct (copied it from Hibernate and executed it manually). So,

given

```
Clazz<Bar> clazz;
Date start, end;
```

this **fails**

```
List<Bar> bars = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(clazz)
    .add(Restrictions.between("timestamp", start, end))
    .list();
```

and this

```
 List<Bar> bars = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
     .createCriteria(clazz)
     .add(Restrictions.ge("timestamp", start))
     .add(Restrictions.le("timestamp", end))
     .list();
```

but this **works**

```
List<Bar> bars = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery("from Bar b where b.timestamp > ? and b.timestamp < ?")
    .setDate(0, start)
    .setDate(1, end)
    .list();
```

---

**The fail observation is:**

1. The number of `Bar` results returned are the same (and correct)
2. but in the **criterion** cases a `Bar` with a `List<Foo>` returns roughly **10x** more `Foo` objects than the corresponding SQL query does. All the extra `Foo` objects are identical copies.

---

**EDIT**

```
@Entity
public class Bar {

    @Id 
    private String id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timestamp;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "bar_foo",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "barid") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fooid") }
    )
    private List<Foo> params;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id private String id;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post Bar class.

Comment: @Floradu88, korifey, `Bar` posted.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg Does [this question and the first answer to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122808/restrictions-between-for-date-in-hibernate-criteria) helps?

Comment: @Kohányi, ty but the problem isn't about inclusive/exclusive search, it's about hibernate returning more `Foo`s than there even exist in the DB.

Comment: Please post all the objects foo that are brought by the working query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember or look up the rationale behind this right now but what you are seeing might be expected behavior. Try this:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite query

```
List<Bar> bars = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
 .createCriteria(Bar.class)
 .add(Restrictions.ge("timestamp", start))
 .add(Restrictions.le("timestamp", end))
 .list();
```

It's the same like you did, but I've never seen examples which variable of class type like you use them.

You should check this link also [HQL(hibernate) timestamp range match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864925/hqlhibernate-timestamp-range-match) also this [Restrictions Between for Date in Hibernate Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122808/restrictions-between-for-date-in-hibernate-criteria)

Edit 2: 
Check the examples in here : http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery102/

Comment: Thanks for answering. It doesn't make a difference. The range query seems to be working, but hibernate assembling the result does not.

Comment: ty, although I get the correct *number* of result back already

Comment: post the solution then:p please

Comment: perhaps my error description is insufficient. But the problem is that I get to many `Foo` objects back. If I should get 1 `Foo` back, I end up with ~10 `Foo` copies instead (but only using Criteria API).